# Common supertype of Java classes

Tags: java, class, oop, reflection

I have two Java `Class` objects at runtime, and I'd like to compute the minimum common supertype, i.e. the most specific class that is the common ancestor of both my classes

Often, this will be `java.lang.Object`, but not always. e.g. if I have `java.lang.Integer` and `java.lang.Double` as my two classes, then the common supertype I would expect to get is `java.lang.Number`.

What's the most effective / canonical way to compute this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would you do this for? Boxing?

Comment: Do you always have 2 classes?

Comment: @Rohit I often have more than 2, but generalising a solution for 2 looks easy enough...

Comment: @JNYRanger - I'm experimenting with my first compiler with a type system - https://github.com/mikera/kiss

Comment: @mikera cool project! Too bad lisp pains me (I'm a Haskell fan though!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
static Class<?> mostSpecificCommonSuperclass(Class<?> a, Class<?> b) {
    Class<?> s = a;
    while (!s.isAssignableFrom(b)) {
        s = s.getSuperclass());
    }
    return s;
}
```

This assumes that you are interested in the most specific common super *class*. A most specific common super *type* isn't well defined, as there may be several equally specific super types. For instance, given

```
class A implements Runnable, Number {}
class B implements Runnable, Number {}
```

should `mostSpecificCommonSupertype(A.class, B.class)` be `Runnable.class` or `Number.class`?

Comment: Thanks - this one solves my immediate problem nicely (I agree the interfaces are going to be tricky, but that's for another time...)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote this really quick, not really sure it works for the more difficult cases. If it doesn't, just comment that it doesn't work and I will remove this answer.

```
private static Class getCommonSuperclass(final Class clazz1, final Class clazz2, final boolean doSuper){
    final Class c1 = doSuper ? clazz1.getSuperclass() : clazz1;
    final Class c2 = doSuper ? clazz2.getSuperclass() : clazz2;
    if(c1 == null || c2 == null)
        return Object.class;
    if(c1.equals(c2))
        return c1;
    Class result = getCommonSuperclass(c1.getSuperclass(), c2, false);
    if(!result.equals(Object.class))
        return result;
    result = getCommonSuperclass(c1, c2.getSuperclass(), false);
    if(!result.equals(Object.class))
        return result;
    return getCommonSuperclass(c1.getSuperclass(), c2.getSuperclass(), false);
}

public static Class getCommonSuperclass(final Class clazz1, final Class clazz2){
    return getCommonSuperclass(clazz1, clazz2, true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(getCommonSuperclass(java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Integer.class));
}
```

The code above prints `class java.lang.Number`.

Note: This code only works with common superclasses, not common interfaces.